# ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using Spring3.1.1 with hibernate4 to implement Spring MVC Project 
While trying to fetch data using Hibernate I am receiving following error

```
ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.xxx.service.ContactService com.vedic.stp.HomeController.contactService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.xxx.service.ContactService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133) [spring-webmvc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:952) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:188) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
```

Controller code:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
    @Autowired
    private ContactService contactService;
    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);
        System.out.println("The is callessing service");
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);
        logger.info("The list size is----"+contactService.listContact());
        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        return "home";
    }

}
```

Service class:

```
@Service
public class ContactServiceImpl implements ContactService {

    @Autowired
    private ContactDAO contactDAO;

    @Transactional
    public void addContact(Contacts contact) {
        contactDAO.addContact(contact);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Contacts> listContact() {

        return contactDAO.listContact();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void removeContact(Integer id) {
        contactDAO.removeContact(id);
    }
}
```

Servlet Context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.stp" />
</beans:beans>
```

I am new to Spring and Hibernate. Please Help me to resolve this Error.

Comment: `No matching bean of type [com.srisys.service.ContactService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency` - that is the problem

Comment: Are you registering the bean ContactService?

Comment: post spring xml file for more help!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply shikjohari, I dont know how to register bean pls provide the info where I have to register

Answer (score 0):

Because your controller bean config code in servlet context file is wrong.
As below statement.

```
<!-- this package must be your controller package -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.stp" />
```

If your package name is true, you need to include all subpackages in com.xxx.stp:I think.

```
<!-- this package must be your controller package -->
            <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx" >
              <context:include-filter type="aspectj" expression="com.xxx.*" />
            </context:component-scan>
```